# Divide and conquer sum of array iterative

Tags: java, arrays, sum, divide-and-conquer

Is it possible to get the sum of an array using divide and conquer? I've tried it, but I always miss some numbers, or I calculate a number twice.

```java
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};

    public int sum(int[] arr) {
        int begin = 0;
        int end = array.length - 1;
        int counter = 0;

        while (begin <= end) {
            int mid = (begin + end) / 2;
            counter += arr[end] + arr[mid];
            end = mid - 1;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, Diveide-and-conquer computation of the array's sum is possible. But I cannot see a UseCase for it? You're still computing at least the same amount of sums, you're still running into issues if the sum of `array`is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, ...

There is also no performance benefit like Codor showed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700362/8383428) to a related question.

Starting with Java 8 you can compute the sum in 1 line using streams.

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(array).sum();
```

The main flaw with your above code is the fact that you're only summing up index `mid`(2) and `end`(4). After that you skip to the lower bracket (index `mid = 0` and `end = 2`). So you're missing index 3. This problem will become even more prevelant with larger arrays because you're skipping even more indices after the `while`'s first iteration.

A quick Google search brought up [this nice-looking talk](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eaprakash/eecs282/lectures/11-recursion.pdf) about the general Divide-and-Conquer principle using a mechanism called *Recursion*. Maybe it can guide you to a working solution.

Comment: It is working, I just failed to write it correctly. And I am supposed to try it with divide and conquer.

Comment: I assume this is a academical problem. Your code is currently not capable of the task because you're only adding the 2 outwards elements of your first DnC interval (`counter=arr[end] + arr[mid]`). Try to debug your code better or at least use System.out to help you - I suggest something along the lines of `System.out.println(String.format("begin=%d; mid=%d; end=%d; counter=%d", begin, mid, end, counter));` after the line I mentioned before. Then you can see your indeices and counter value change.

Comment: @Der_Reperator Thank you, I will try it.

Comment: I have already done it with recursion, but I thought it would be nice to have it the iterative way and recursive way.